# React - Get component position relative the viewport onScroll , preferably in percentage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, position

hoping to find some good solutions as I am struggling to figure this one out, and haven't found any libraries.

What I need exactly is tracking a Component's position (Y) when scrolling, and only when its in viewport.
When a component enters the viewport at the bottom I'd need a 0, and when same component's bottom reaching the top of the viewport I'd need 100. (or vice versa). Also can be multiple component on the same page.

This is what I have so far as a simple functional component. Any help appreciated! thanks

Also CodeSandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-bird-yyq24?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"

const SepFramer = () => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);
    const sepRef = useRef();

  function logIt() {
    let offsetTop = sepRef.current.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(offsetTop)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function watchScroll() {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", logIt);
    }
    watchScroll();
    // Remove listener (like componentWillUnmount)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", logIt);
    };
  });  

  return (
    <div className="separator" ref={sepRef}>
        Content
    </div>
  )
}

export default SepFramer
```

Comment: Do you use `SepFramer ` like `<App> <SepFramer/></App>`?

Comment: @alex Sure , it is a component within <App>

Answer (score 0):

When component cross viewport's bottom

```
Math.round(((window.innerHeight-offsetTop) * 100) / sepRef.current.clientHeight)
```

Comment: not really the desired effect, 1 step further though, its 0 when components on top please try it for yourself, just updated the info with a CodeSandbox link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/get-percentage-of-an-element-in-viewport-yqprx